# shell$ExitCodeException in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

[image]
I keep getting this error , I have tried executing it many times. It shows the same error and re executes itself about two more times and then exits

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when running a job remotely, the yarn.application.classpath must be in the configuration otherwise the job will fail

For running the job please use this configration

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.set(“fs.defaultFS”, “hdfs://192.168.195.161:8020″);
configuration.set(“hadoop.job.ugi”, “root”);
configuration.set(“mapreduce.framework.name”, “yarn”);
configuration.set(“yarn.resourcemanager.address”a “192.168.195.161:8050″);
configuration.set(“yarn.nodemanager.aux-services”, “mapreduce_shuffle”);

final String[] args = new String[] { };
ToolRunner.run(configuration, jobDriver, args);
```